# React starter app to create/bundle both client and server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I've created a starter app using the React starter app (create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts)

This is working fine.  I've also ejected the scripts so that the app can do automatic processing/reloading of *.scss files. 
Other than the extra scss handling, this is using the out of the box webpack config/bundling.

Now I want to create a server side component to this so that I can create some REST services.  I can see that the WebpackDevServer is using express, but what I'm unsure of is how do I go about setting this up within the existing React project config.

So is it better to create a new project that is purely for the server side (REST services) and run that independently or can I change the webpack configuration so the one project can handle both - if so how?

Comment: https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-backend/

Comment: That looks just the business :) I'll need to wait till later to give it a go - but looks interesting.

Comment: That site was what I was looking for. With a small change to npm scripts I've now got my client/server all being served up with one command.  If you write the above as an answer I'll mark it as correct.